# Three theorems for the price of one? (like duality)

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, duality-theorems

Why the notion of "duality" (when we get two theorems for the price of one) are ubiquitous in mathematics (order and lattice theory, category theory, group theory), but "triality" (three theorems for the price of one) is much less common?

Is there a fundamental reason for this?

Remark: In my research I met a case when there are three different order isomorphic sets, but apart of being order isomorphic, their structures are very different, so that I could not call this "triality".

Comment: Actually, if there were three things related as in a duality, I'd expect six theorems for the price of one - and that would be too good to be rue

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why six?

Comment: Duality is a different concept.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triality (for vector spaces)

Comment: This is a very good question. Please be patient for a few days and I wll write an hopefully good answer.